# How to inverse the order of form submissions on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I recently created a Google form and linked the responses to Google Sheets (so that the submissions to the Google form were automatically inserted on the sheet).
However, **I would like the latest responses to appear on top of the sheets, rather than them compiling "downwards"**.
Is there any way to do this?

To clarify my question if you didn't understand it: If a response is entered at say 1 PM and another response at 2 PM, then the 1 PM response is on the first row of the sheets, and the 2 PM one on the second- I would like to "switch" this order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new tab/sheet and use the following formula in cell `A1`

```
=QUERY(Responses!A1:Z,"where A is not null order by A",1)
```

*(please -as always- adjust formula according to your ranges and locale)*

Comment: I think you want "order by A desc" there.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I ended up using the order by desc formula, and it works now. As I am a new user, I cannot upvote your posts, but I have accepted the answers.